# Elections nominations posts not showing up in API

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, questions, elections

I know that it's probably unintended that the Primary voting scores were leaked by the API, but I think if you're going to remove it, then at least make it official, so I won't have to wonder if it's just a transient bug.

Anyway, some background: It's possible to collect the score and up/downvote count and scores of each nominee by accessing the post id referred to in the nominations' HTML:

```
<div id="post-4791995">
```

They appear on the API [as questions](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/4791995). Some time yesterday, however, the up/downvote counts were wiped, and new candidates' nominations that appear after these do not appear in the API any more. I need to know if this is by design, so that I can stop [my stats page](http://se.awio.com/election.html) from polling for useless data in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They were never intended to appear, and [this bug fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76622/are-election-primary-votes-intended-to-count-towards-your-qa-votes) incidentally removed them from the API.